# What is this error about?

Tags: dynamic-linking, static-linking

ALL,

I'm using Anjuta to do my development.

I created a project for my main application, and then made 2 more: 1 for the static library (libdbinterface.a) and 1 for the dynamic library (libsqlite_lib.so).

Both those libraries contains one exported class each: libdbinterface.a - class Database, libsqlite_lib.so - public SQLiteDatabase : public Database.

Now I'm trying to link libdbinterface.a to libsqlite_lib.so.

So in Anjuta I added following to the "Linker Option" for the target libsqlite_lib.so:

> -L/home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/dbinterface -ldbinterface

However, trying to compile I received following error from linker:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.4/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/dbinterface/libdbinterface.a(database.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_ZTV8Database' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

I tried to recompile libsqlite_lib.so with -fPIC explicitely added to "C++ Options" of that project but that didn't solve it - I still receive the same error.

Unfortunately trying to Google on how to link .a and .so is not helpful.

Can someone sched some light on how to fix this error?

TIA.

[EDIT]
libsqlite_lib.so Makefile - https://bpaste.net/show/1495231e58cc
libdbinterface.a Makefile - https://bpaste.net/show/3a71c119d0fc

libdbinterface.a contains 2 files databse.h:

```
#ifndef DBMANAGER_DATABASE
#define DBMANAGER_DATABASE

class Field
{
public:
    Field(const std::string &columnName, const std::string &columnType, const std::string &columnDefaultValue = "", const bool columnIsNull = false, const bool columnPK = false)
    {
        column_name = columnName;
        column_type = columnType;
        column_defaultValue = columnDefaultValue;
        column_isNull = columnIsNull;
        column_pk = columnPK;
    }
private:
    std::string column_name, column_type, column_defaultValue;
    bool column_isNull, column_pk;
};

struct FKField
{
    FKField(const std::string &table_name, const std::string &original_field, const std::string &referenced_field)
    {
        tableName = table_name;
        originalField = original_field;
        referencedField = referenced_field;
    }
    std::string tableName, originalField, referencedField;
};

class Table
{
public:
    Table(const std::string &tableName, const std::vector<Field> &tableFields, const std::map<int,std::vector<FKField> > &foreignKeys)
    {
        table_name = tableName;
        table_fields = tableFields;
        foreign_keys = foreignKeys;
    }
    const std::string &GetTableName() { return table_name; }
    std::map<int,std::vector<FKField> > &GetForeignKeyVector() { return foreign_keys; }
private:
    std::string table_name;
    std::vector<Field> table_fields;
    std::map<int,std::vector<FKField> > foreign_keys;
};

#ifdef WIN32
class __declspec(dllexport) Database
#else
class Database
#endif
{
private:
    struct Impl;
    Impl *pimpl;
public:
    Database();
    virtual ~Database();
    Impl &GetTableVector();
    static void *operator new(std::size_t size);
    static void operator delete(void *ptr, std::size_t size);
    virtual int Connect(const char *selectedDSN, std::vector<std::wstring> &errorMsg);
    virtual int GetTableListFromDb(std::string &) { return 0; }
};

#endif
```

and database.cpp:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#endif
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include "database.h"

struct Database::Impl
{
    std::vector<Table> m_tables;
};

Database::Database() : pimpl( new Impl )
{
}

Database::~Database()
{
    delete pimpl;
}

void *Database::operator new(std::size_t size)
{
    return ::operator new( size );
}

void Database::operator delete(void *ptr, std::size_t size)
{
    return ::operator delete( ptr );
}

Database::Impl &Database::GetTableVector()
{
    return *pimpl;
}

int Database::Connect(const char *selectedDSN, std::vector<std::wstring> &errorMsg)
{
    selectedDSN = selectedDSN;
    errorMsg = errorMsg;
    return 0;
}
```

libsqlite_lib.so has also 2 files: database_sqlite.h

```
#ifndef DBMANAGER_SQLITE
#define DBMANAGER_SQLITE

#ifdef WIN32
class __declspec(dllexport) SQLiteDatabase : public Database
#else
class SQLiteDatabase : public Database
#endif
{
public:
    SQLiteDatabase();
    ~SQLiteDatabase();
    virtual int Connect(const char *selectedDSN, std::vector<std::wstring> &errorMsg);
    virtual int GetTableListFromDb(std::vector<std::wstring> &errorMsg);
protected:
    void GetErrorMessage(int code, std::wstring &errorMsg);
private:
    sqlite3 *m_db;
};

#endif
```

and database_sqlite.cpp with the actual implementation.
[/EDIT]

Comment: Add some example code exhibiting the problem, please. Don't forget to include a Makefile or other build recipe.

Comment: @Theophrastus, what is libccd.a? I explicitely link against /home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libdbinterface/libdbinterface.a and this file is only one. Unless what you saying is that Anjuta explicitely trying to link against the installed version of the library and this one.

Comment: @FaheemMitha, the Makefiles are huge. I can probably drop them somewhere and put the link to them here.

Comment: I added some code to make the problem clearer.

Comment: The idea is to make as small an example as possible that still exhibits the problem. This should not require a huge Makefile.

Comment: @FaheemMitha, As I said, I'm working with Anjuta. And Anjuta does create a big Makefile after running "configure & friends". And that the reason I'm working with IDE - I have no idea how to make the Makefile by hand. Can you help by looking at the error?

Comment: You could learn to use either `autotools` or `cmake`. These also generate large Makefiles, but the recipe for generating them is relatively small and simple. Also, for a simple project, creating a Makefile is not difficult; you could learn how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently the solution is to rebuild static library with "-fPIC", not the dynamic one.

Thank you for reading.